# $\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}\ge\frac{2}a+\frac{2}b-\frac{2}c$ if $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to solve $\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}\ge\frac{2}a+\frac{2}b-\frac{2}c$ for $a,b,c>0$.

I tried bringing everything to the common denominator. I got this: $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 2bc + 2ca - 2ab$. How is this solved?

Comment: I think this is the time you start using latex.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956900).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $a,b,c>0$ multiplying through by $abc,$ we need $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge2bc+2ca-2ab\iff (a+b-c)^2\ge0$$ which holds true as $a,b,c$ are real

Answer (score 0):

setting
$b=a+u,c=a+u+v$, with $u\geq 0,v\geq 0$ we get $(a-v)^2\geq 0$ which is true.