# Prove that $(ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2 \geq 144$ , if $a+b=4, c+d=6$.

Tags: inequality

I got that $(ac)^{2}+(bd)^{2}+(ad)^{2}+(bc)^{2} \geq 144$. How is this one solved?

Comment: How did you get this ?

Comment: I suppose the OP means that s/he simplified the inequality to be proved to that form.

Comment: @taninamdar But then he did the same what you did in your answer ?

Comment: I've deleted my answer after I realized that.

Comment: Hint: use the Brahmagupta's identity and it should all become easy from there.

Comment: I've actually just solved it through QM>AM. Now is it required on this site for me to write a solution?

Comment: @SabitAman, yes, please edit your question so that it explains your solution.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956725).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$

**Method** $\#1:$

Assuming $a,b$ are real,

$(a-b)^2\ge0\iff a^2+b^2\ge2ab\iff2(a^2+b^2)\ge(a+b)^2=4^2$

Similarly, for $c^2+d^2$

**Method** $\#2:$

Assuming $a,c$ are real,

$a^2+b^2=a^2+(4-a)^2=2(a^2-4a+8)=2[(a-2)^2+4]\ge2\cdot4$

Similarly, for $c^2+d^2$

**See also**: [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity)

Answer (score 1):

mate, you have already solved it. I'm sorry, this is not an answer but a comment. I don't have the comment privilege. Please, regard this as a comment.

You see, $(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(ac)^2+(bd)^2+(ad)^2+(bc)^2$, so, just add **QED**, or whatever you wish to add.
If you have rather asked **how to reach to this point**, don't vote me down and rather ask me to delete this comment.

I know how to get this job done. So, your response may lead me to make an answer.

Comment: What's the problem? I clearly wrote that I got it myself and it is not the question.

Comment: The Sheik is saying that since the two expressions are equal, if one of them is at least 144, then the other one is too, of course.